# Star Icon, What does it do?

Tags: support, bookmarks

What does the rounded star icon do exactly on http://stackoverflow.com? I cant find anything in the FAQ or on meta about it.

Thanks.

Comment: See this answer - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/the-official-faq-for-stack-overflow-server-fault-and-super-user/7940#7940

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When it says *"this is a favorite question"* when you mouse over it, it's the way to add a question to your -well- favourites, a quick way to revisit these questions from your user profile.

Comment: Ok thanks, thought it would be something simple like that!